# Ajax in drupal 7 dont return values

Tags: views, ajax

Im in drupal 7, i need to make a select with many options, depends of the option taken, in a textarea will be loaded several values in a string.

After hours of test i come here for help.

Im working on a basic page:

```
function ajax_load_all_admins($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['changethis'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            '' => '',
            '1' => 'Cargar todos los admins'
        ),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' => 'ajax_load_all_admins_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'listaCorreos-div'
        )
    );

    $form['listaCorreos'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="listaCorreos-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );

    if (!empty($form_state['values']['changethis'])) {
        $payments_list = db_query('QUERY WORKING WELL');  

        $value = '';
        foreach ($payments_list as $payment) {
            $value .= $payment->admin . ',';
        }
        trim($value, ',');
        $form['listaCorreos']['#default_value'] = $value;
    }

    return $form;
}

function ajax_load_all_admins_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['listaCorreos'];
}

$form = drupal_get_form('ajax_load_all_admins');
print drupal_render($form);
```

The Ajax call is working but i only recibe:

```
0: {command:settings, settings:{basePath:/, pathPrefix:,…}, merge:true}
```

No other one position.

I think it can be for the drupal_render, but dont know why?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 week searching and trying things at home i decide to make a separate module for the form.

When i pass the code to a module all works fine with the same code.

I think for any reason Drupal needs to render form by his own, not forced like i was doing with the next code in a simple view:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('ajax_load_all_admins');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Hope this help, **dont try to make Ajax calls inside a simple view** like i tried.

Comment: '#ajax' callback is not working. why? I've added my question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166959/ajax-is-not-working-with-drupal-renderdrupal-get-form