# '#ajax' is not working with drupal_render(drupal_get_form())

Tags: ajax, forms

I've a html form in a page. And also I've added another form at end of the form. My code should look like something below:

```
$customer_details = array('name' => 'Guru');
$form['#suffix'] = '<div class="row"><div id="customers-box" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:white;">' . drupal_render(drupal_get_form('test_customer_info_form', $customer_details)) . '</div></div>';
```

Now I've  two form in a page.
My customer info form have below code:

```
function test_customer_info_form($form, &$form_state, $details) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Name',
    '#default_value' => $details['name'],
  );
  $form['submit-customer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'customer_submit', 'class' => array('btn-primary')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'customer_custom_form_submit',
      'wrapper'  => 'customers-box',
    ),
  );
  return  $form;
}

function customer_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  print_r($form_state['values']);exit;
}
```

Now '#ajax' is not triggered while submitting form. But form submit handler is working fine. I can get form state values by test_customer_info_form_submit(). I want to get form values by '#ajax'. Is any suggestions?

**Answer:**

 The problem is my side. Because i've added 'id' using '#attributes' in form submit button. My id override the '#ajax' callback button id. Thats is the problem. Now i've removed 'id' from submit button. Now it is working fine.

**Note: if you use '#ajax' callback for your form, make sure don't set 'id' attribute for submit button**

Comment: I would move the second form to a block that is placed below your other form. It feels it can get messy to include a form in the declaration of another form.

Comment: Now it looks like you told. The form is place after one form is completed. '#ajax' callback for first form is working fine but another form is not triggered. I've used two separate '#ajax'  calls